# Set up TextView's background to fill only my text - Java

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a question about my chatview layout.

I have in my layout some textviews. Some of these have layout_width equals to match_parent and gravity set to right. 
My problem is this: textview's background fills all the space available to textview and not only my text in textview.
How can I set my textview's background to fill only my text?

This is my list's Adapter:

```
    private class CommentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<COMMENT> {

    RelativeLayout listLayout;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsTxt;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsImg;

    public CommentAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<COMMENT> comments) {
        super(context, -1, -1, comments);
        listLayout = new RelativeLayout(CommentPage.this);

        paramsTxt = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        paramsImg = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        paramsImg.height = width_square*7;
        paramsImg.width = width_square*7;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        COMMENT single_comment = null;
        RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();
        options.centerCrop();

        if (convertView == null) {
            // if convertView is null
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_comment, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            // initialize views
            holder.textView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment_text);
            holder.imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment_image);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (CommentPage.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            holder.imageView.setBackground(null);
        }

        single_comment = getItem(position);

        if(single_comment.senderId.equals(myId)) {
            holder.textView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            paramsTxt.setMargins(width_square*20,width_square*2,
                    width_square*5,width_square*2);
            holder.textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_right);
            holder.textView.setLayoutParams(paramsTxt);
        } else {
            paramsTxt.setMargins(width_square*5,width_square*2,
                    width_square*20,width_square*2);
            paramsImg.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            paramsTxt.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.comment_image);
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_profile);
            holder.textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_left);
            paramsImg.setMargins(width_square*5,width_square*2,
                    0,width_square*2);
            holder.imageView.setLayoutParams(paramsImg);
            holder.textView.setLayoutParams(paramsTxt);
        }

        holder.textView.setText(single_comment.text);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

[image: chatview picture]

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: as you said , you give match_parent to your textview

Comment: I set match_parent because otherwise setGravity(right) has no affect

Comment: So is the image what you want or what you don't want?

Comment: It's the image I don't want

Comment: so then don't you just want "wrap_content" instead of "match_parent?"

Comment: Why aren't you using XML to implement this feature? It's more easier. Also you have to give the `wrap_content` parameter instead of match_parent.

Comment: wrap_content will do.

Comment: Thank you to all.

Comment: seems your are using hardoce for sizes , prevent from this . give sizes in your xml layout file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `"wrap_content"` instead of `"match_parent"` for your width on those text views.

:)

Comment: Ok Thank you boober bunz ;)